# A part of div on another div when the second div's overflow is hidden

Tags: html, css

I have a div and I want to place a part of it on another div. It should look like following:

[image]
Image 1

I have managed to come up with the code below, which works fine if I remove `overflow:hidden;` from the div `imageSlider` but if I don't then it gives me the following result:

[image]
Image 2

You can check code live here: http://jsfiddle.net/Y52fu/

But I have to use `overflow:hidden;` as a CSS rule for the div `imageSlider` because it is actually a div for an image slider. If don't use it then the image slider loses it functionality.

Could you please tell me how can achieve the result like shown in the image 1, keeping the `overflow:hidden;` for the div `imageSlider` ?

HTML

```
<div class="imageSlider">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="slideCaption1">
            <div class="slideText1"><span>PARIS</span></div>        
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
.imageSlider{    
    width:400px;
    overflow:hidden;    
}

.box{
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:green;
    position:relative
}

.slideCaption1 {    
    top: 20px;
    right:-12px;
    position: absolute; 
    background: rgb(000, 000, 000); 
    background: rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.75);
}

.slideText1{
    color: white;   
    font-size:22px;
    line-height:35px;
    padding-left: 9px;
    padding-right: 9px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;    
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-right:15%;
    margin-left:9%;
    text-transform:uppercase;   
 }
```

### Update

Please check this link to see the actual code from my project : http://jsfiddle.net/P7mdV/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a clearfix to preserve the layout. Remove the 'overflow: hidden' from the main div and add the clearfix class. Then add to your css:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";    
  display: block;    
  height: 0;    
  overflow: hidden; 
}
.clearfix:after {clear: both;}
.clearfix {zoom: 1;} /* IE < 8 */
```

See my fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Y52fu/1/

Edit: with your new example it's using a lot more complex layout and the bootstrap styles, so the same fix won't apply. I had to play with it a bit since the carousel-inner needs to have the content hidden outside of the width set, it seems like adding a padding works, if it's set to the same as the right offset. The only issue is that the text jumps a little once it slides into place.

```
.carousel {
    width: 400px;
} 
.carousel-inner {
    padding-right: 12px;
}
```

I set an explicit width on the images too just because they jump a bit if you don't (since 100% of the width changes as they slide into view and have the padding in place). You can see it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/P7mdV/3/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried your code but the `clearfix` does seem to work.

Comment: I have tried your code in my real project. Please check this, http://jsfiddle.net/P7mdV/1/

Comment: That's just because it is now using bootstrap default styles. You'll need to override the .carousel-inner class which has an overflow: hidden. See my edit above.

Comment: thanks again for your reply. I checked your jsfiddle but the image slider is not sliding the images in correct way if I use your code. Would you please kindly check again?

Comment: Well, I gave it another shot. Another option is to 'fake' it by using images with a set border the same color as your bg. But, I tried a css solution above and updated the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change .box position attribute from relative to absolute and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but if I use "absolute" the things under it goes up  :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this
HTML Code: where i have placed slideCaption1 outside imageSlider

```
<div class="slideCaption1"">
    <div class="slideText1"><span>PARIS</span></div>        
</div>

<div class="imageSlider">
    <div class="box">

    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 9;
right: 119px;
top: 20px;
```

From this code you don't have to remove overflow:hidden property from div imageSlider.